# How do I get a parent node through recursion in python?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

In python, using constructors and Class I have created nodes. I need to get its parent and their parent nodes. I have got that node, its parent(that has marked when created by a constructor).

I also tried to create a function to print a node and its parents. However how do I pass the parents'parent node so i can get that also.

Comment: You really should add the code for your classes  otherwise it’s hard to make a meaningful answer.

Comment: We'd need to see the code; as an [mcve] ideally. The basic class and the function you're working with would help.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you didnt show any code its hard to tell what your really trying to do. However assuming your mean nodes like in a tree then below simple example shows how you could recursivly work back up the tree to show the relationships. this of course is not a complete example but should give you an idea.

```py
class node():
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        self.name = name
        self.parent: node = parent

    def get_bottom_up_ancestors(self):
        if self.parent:
            return [self.name] + self.parent.get_bottom_up_ancestors()
        return [self.name]

    def get_top_down_ancestors(self):
        return self.get_bottom_up_ancestors()[::-1]


root = node("Top")
child1 = node("first", parent=root)
child2 = node("second", parent=root)
grandchild1 = node("grandchild", parent=child1)

print(grandchild1.get_bottom_up_ancestors())
print(grandchild1.get_top_down_ancestors())
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['grandchild', 'first', 'Top']
['Top', 'first', 'grandchild']
```

Comment: Yes! It is something like this! But is there any way to recursively add the inputs("Top", "first","second","grandchild"). If it were given in the input for example.

Comment: How would you decide which elements would be children of other ones. For example first and second are siblings

Comment: Yeah, that's how the question was.  The input would be given like that.

Comment: This isn't a homework site. If this is an assignment you should attempt it and if its not working post your code and expected input or output x

Comment: The siblings are irrelavant. The only thing that matters is the parent. and their parent.

Answer (score -1):

I don't quite understand what you are talking about but from what I DO understand there is no such thing as a parent object only parent classes so a node parent would not be possible

Comment: For example in a binary tree, the parent will be parent node and child will be the 2 child nodes it point towards, right.

Comment: A "parent node" isn't a part of the language, it's, as mentioned, used in tree structures. It would be a reference to the object that's considered to be the parent of another object.